# What you can not do with Angular.js out of the box which you can do with jQuery

Tags: jquery, angularjs, javascript, javascript-framework

What you can not do with Angular.js out of the box which you can do with jQuery?

What problems I might face if I switch from jQuery to Angular? Basically my code consists of many *onclick* -> *make ajax call* -> *add or remove some elements, change css, replace some text*

Comment: Too open-ended:  http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/how-do-i-think-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background

Answer (score 4):

"Games, and GUI editors are examples of very intensive and tricky DOM manipulation. These kinds of apps are different from CRUD apps, and as a result are not a good fit for Angular. In these cases using something closer to bare metal such as jQuery may be a better fit." -- [Overview doc](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/overview)